# Implement Okta Single Sign-On (SAML) authentication

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta

I want to implement SAML 2.0 based OKTA SSO authentication for my application and after successfully authenticate from OKTA SSO it will return first-name, last-name and email from OKTA

I search over web but not able to find any solution for implementation

Comment: Okta has tons of examples and there are many more for OIDC/Oauth and even SAML.  What have you done so far?

Comment: I have created a demo application using https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml but i want to implement this example in java

Comment: Please check this article, describing a potential solution to your task https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-saml

Comment: Can we pass metadata url dynamically ?

Comment: if you successfully logged in you will get many more things , refer below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861411/httpcontext-getowincontext-authentication-getexternallogininfoasync-always-r