# Integrate third party okta into the spring boot application

Tags: okta, spring-boot-starter

I am fairly new to OKTA. I read few articles and I managed to setup a spring boot application to work with my okta instance. I used okta-spring-boot-starter dependency to make this work. This worked just fine.

However, my actual requirement is that when a user from company A tries to login into my application, I want the authentication process to be taken care my company A's OKTA. Can I configure this and make the post login redirection happen to my app?

Is this possible? I have tried multiple things but nothing has worked for me. Please guide me. Thank you!!

EDIT: I want to work with OKTA OIDC.

Comment: you may find useful context
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861411/httpcontext-getowincontext-authentication-getexternallogininfoasync-always-r

Answer (score 0):

SAML acts based on pre-configured trust relationship (metadata, including certificates and audience restriction) between IdP and you (SP). What you are trying to create is a SP, which will trust any (?) IdP which will send an assertion to you :) (assuming you are capable of verifying the signature for the assertion, which requires you having public key for IdP... you see where I'm heading with that, hopefully)

I don't believe spring is capable of dealing with multiple IdP's. But with a custom code it might be possible, if you know how to obtain information from IdP to verify their signature for the assertion

Comment: Hi @Philipp, Thank you!! I have edited the question, actually I missed to mention that I want to work with OKTA OIDC. In this case, will your opinion change?

Comment: Oh, sorry, for whatever reason I thought about SAML. For OIDC, again, to redirect users to authZ server for authentication you need to know server URL. I believe (not an expert on Spring) that it's not supported. Again, manually it'll probably be possible to do, assuming, you know which authZ server to send your users to for authentication (maybe based on their email address or something like that). You can think of it as having a site where you'd need 2 or 3 buttons, like "Login with A", "Login with B"... (like Google/FB/MS)