# Okta Angular Error : getUserInfo requires an access token object

Tags: okta

In our angular 13 SPA application, we have integrated the Okta SSO. After successful login via the okta singIn widget window, we are trying to fetch the authenticated user information but getting the below error:

AuthSdkError: getUserInfo requires an access token object AuthSdkError: get user info requires an access token object.

How to get resolved this error, any help/suggestion on this will be appreciated.

Comment: it would help if you attach your app Okta config as a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Do you request `token` in your app configuration? Or only `id_token`? If latter, then include `token` as well

Comment: Hi, I have a login page, after login, it is navigating the home page, in the home.component.ts I'm calling okta user information.

Comment: capture network traffic and analyze what your application requesting from Okta in the `/authorize` call, if you can't post your configuration snippet

Comment: you may find some useful context 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861411/httpcontext-getowincontext-authentication-getexternallogininfoasync-always-r