# OKTA /token post request from java

Tags: java, token, okta

Getting this error when calling /token endpoint of OKTA from java code

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)

Here is my post request -I am using Java 1.6. Is anything wrong with this REST call -

```
                 URL url = new URL("https://dev.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token");
                 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                 connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 connection.setDoInput(true);
                 connection.setDoOutput(true);
                 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");             
                 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                 connection.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "authorization_code");
                 connection.setRequestProperty("client_id","111111");
                 connection.setRequestProperty("client_secret","22222");
                 connection.setRequestProperty("scope","openid");
                 connection.setRequestProperty("redirect_uri","my application url");
                 connection.setRequestProperty("code","hhlhhluyiyo");
                 connection.connect();
                 System.out.println(">>responce code >>"+connection.getResponseCode());
                 output = connection.getResponseMessage();   
                 System.out.println(">>>>"+output);
             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: It seems likely that the prehistoric version of Java is unable to handle modern TLS.  Can you attempt it with something newer?

Comment: try to add on before call 
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861411/httpcontext-getowincontext-authentication-getexternallogininfoasync-always-r

you may find something related